# Samples on AndEngine

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I want to learn AndEngine.

How should I start?  I don't see any good examples.  I even tried finding the downloadable source code for AndEngine and MagneTank but no luck.

Comment: look on my answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605799/how-to-get-started-with-andengine/19610680#19610680

Answer (score 8):

I suggest http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html which includes many tutorials. These are often supported by code examples. I especially suggest the "Full game tutorial articles series". With this you will develop a game from scratch and learn very much about the AndEngine.

Answer (score 6):

Try to checkout their project from [here](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/) and download some sample source from internet e.g. [here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples) and run the examples keeping both source in a common project.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for learning basic AndEngine game programming, I suggest looking at this book: [AndEngine for Android Game Development Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184951898X).

This is a very good way to start. I have learned it in just 1 week, and am now creating my own game.

Answer (score 5):

Drop Block is an exampmle from google play store.

http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/

and the famous example towers......> http://www.raywenderlich.com/12065/how-to-create-a-simple-android-game

Answer (score 3):

Since AndEngine is composed of several sublibraries I created a `repo` manifest to use in order to have all the needed to try the examples.

You can find it here: https://github.com/gipi/AndEngine-repo

Answer (score 1):

Many People have already answered here and I think they all are right:

But I want to include my answer as well , because I started as a rookie in AndEngine and now I am still a rookie but with a little more knowledge than earlier.

1) Install the [AndEngine APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.anddev.andengine.examples&hl=de) from Google Play, test all the functionality this engine shows in that, see if the game you are thinking to make is possible with all those tools in the APK.

2) As soon as you are ready go to [github page of AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) and install it.

3) Tweak the Example (MOST IMPORTANT), you will not learn what AndEngine is and what it can or cant do unless you tweak the examples in the AndEngine library.

4) Now you have a basic understanding, so its time to start a game.

5) Go to matim-dev blog on how to make a complete game tutorial , it is the best tutorial on andengine so far in Internet.

6) If any problem ask your question in the andengine forum , well they never answer quickly but all the problems you will face are already discussed there so no problem just go for it and start AndEngine.

Pros and cons of AndEngine so far for me :

**Pros :**

i) not well documented, but still you can tweak the code easily and understand very fast.
ii) Use of Box2D is great with this, Animation Sprite everything works fine.

**cons**

i) Very slow compared to other frameworks, deleting and detaching bodies and sprites is very clumsy, after 3 months of development of AndEngine today also I am facing problems with deleting sprites and detaching bodies in AndEngine.

ii) Attaching google ads is a nightmare in AndEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Try some basic app development on Android to get Fimilar with environemt.

But to get basic concepts you should read first chapter of

> AndEngine for Android Game  Development Cookbook by Jayme Schroeder
>   and Brian Broyles

from [here](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781849518987_Chapter_01.pdf)

Create a account on Github(and fetch the code)/or download the AndEngine(Zip) locally. and experiment with examples.

further more, Download andEngine Android app to see examples in Motion!!
This is also useful link: [Java Code Geeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/tutorials/android-tutorials/android-game-tutorials/)