# How to get started with andengine

Tags: android, andengine, 2d-games

Are there any good resources to get started with Andengine? Any good tutorials, blogs or books?

Of course, I have visited its official website http://www.andengine.org/, but I didn't think the documentation they have is a good starting point.

Comment: You have to visit this tutorial site matim-dev.com/tutorials.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started with AndEngine not long ago, these are the thing that helped me :

1. Download the AndEngine Examples from Play store, there is source code of it in Nicolas Gramlich's github:

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich

1. Developing Small Space invader from scratch :
   https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/jimvaders-my-own-invaders-clone-thingie-tutorial/
2. Matthew's blog - almost everything is there, plus there is a small game part development there
3. two books : a - AndEngine for android game development cookbook(Latest AndEngine version)
   b - learn android game programming(2011)

Comment: http://www.matim-dev.com/ this is the link for Matthew's blog , couldn't add it to the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Below link will help you to get started with AndEngine

[mybringback](http://www.mybringback.com/series/andengine-gles2-android-game-development/)

Comment: I need list of videos,blogs or books for getting started with and engine not only one link

Comment: You just go through that link it is much more than a link what you are asking is already in there

Answer (score 0):

This is the book - "AndEngine for Android Game Development Cookbook".